# Thank you comments

Tags: discussion

If someone provides a helpful answer you can upvote it.

There is no reason to make "thank you" comments underneath answers or thank people in advance by saying "thank you" or "thanks" when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional info regarding etiquette surrounding [answers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [comments](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).